# System.Web.Helper.Json.Deserialze() maxJsonLength is ignored

Tags: c#

I have tried using both

```
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

and

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2147483647" />
  </appSettings>
```

and nether seem to stop

```
dynamic jsonObject = System.Web.Helper.Json.Decode(reallyLongString);
```

from throwing the same maxJsonLength is to low exception. Does anyone know how I can Decode a json object to dynamic and set the maxJsonLength?

Just for note, I am not in a asp.net web context. This is a desktop cli application.

**EDIT 1:**

The actual Json I am trying to decode is about 2,550,603 characters long (endline type might make that off by 1 lol) As far as I know, I am not using web services or WCF. I am not sending anything. I am trying to decode from a HttpReponse.

Comment: How long is the string? Can you provide the specific exception? There are multiple places where the max length is set. Also, are you using web services or WFC or something else for sending the serialized data?

Comment: @rene thanks ill make sure to not do that next time.

Comment: I suggest using Json.NET like Yuval recommends. Here is a link that might help you on your quest - http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/parsing-big-records-with-jsonnet/240165316

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) 4.0 and above, there is dynamic support out of the box, so you can do:

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse("{username: 12345, password: 111}");
Console.Writeline(d.username);
```

and it works.